# Instantiating non static inner classes

Tags: java

Hello guys I'm trying to instantiate a inner class called AdminHR, with outer class been Administrator which is abstract.

Using this syntax ,   Administrator.AdminHR OBj =OBj.new AdminHR  ();

But it says OBj has not initialized. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Considering you're declaring a variable named `OBj` in the same line, what do you think the `OBj` in `OBj.new AdminHR();` refers to?

Comment: Things get very confusing when you make an inner class extend the containing class.  In particular, when you use a field or a method in the outer class, it gets difficult to follow whether the `this` reference will be the inner object or the outer object.  Don't do that.

Comment: Does it refer to the out class object so I can access the inner class ?  Because I would normally declared the object of the outer class on the first line and use that object on the second line when I instantiate the inner class . But in this case the other loop Administrator is abstract . I'm strin to find a syntax that won't give me this error "an inclosed instance is required that contains Administrator.AdminHR "

Comment: Forget the inner/outer class concept for now. If I write `String ERROR = ERROR.toString();`, what do you expect that to do? Do you expect it to compile? Why?

Comment: I don't think that would compile . #thinking ,nah it won't compile

Comment: It might help to explain what it is about your application that makes you think you need an inner class. (My guess is probably you don't need an inner class.)

Answer (score -2):

Inner classes can be marked `static`. If they are, everything is normal (in fact, you should always make all your inner classes `static` unless you really know what you are doing and you thought it through). If they are not, and in your case, AdminHR is not, well:

1. This class silently has all the generics of the outer, but sort of slyly/invisibly and in a way that's very annoying. Really, you should probably rewrite the thing to be static to avoid the inevitable confusion, and...
2. There is an invisible field, of the type of your outer class, which is `final`. The constructor has an invisible parameter of the type of your outer class, to set that field. You can refer to this field via the expression: `OuterClass.this`, from within the inner class. The compiler will silently insert this in front of any instance method calls or field accesses to the outer class.

When you call `new InnerClass()` in an 'instance context' inside the outer class (so, for example, a non-static method in the outer), then `this` is invisibly passed for that invisible first parameter. So far, so good.

When you are NOT in such a context, you need to actually have an instance of outer to pass along for that invisible parameter to set the invisible field. The syntax for this is very funky, its: `instanceOfOuter.new NonStaticInnerType()`.

You're trying this in your snippet, but, as the compiler correctly reports, OBj is not initialized. In fact, OBj is not even of the right type (it should be an Administator, not an AdminHR).

The solution is then either:

```
Administrator admin = new Administator();
Administrator.AdminHR hr = admin.new AdminHR();
```

or, if you'are already in a non-static method inside the Administator class, just:

```
Administrator.AdminHR hr = new AdminHR();
```

or more likely, forget about non-static inner classes, that's some rocket science exotic java. Solve the problem by making AdminHR itself static. If you do still need to refer to instance stuff from Administator, make that invisible field explicit, so, something like:

```
public class Administator {
    public static class AdminHR {
        private final Administrator admin;

        public AdminHR(Administrator admin) {
            this.admin = admin;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Administrator` is an abstract class and cannot be instantiated. Your last example is completely redundant and inefficient; why is there an Administrator instance that is passed in AdminHR's constructor ? These kind of answers are more likely to do harm, than good; to the OP and other beginners reading it

Comment: The last answer posits: Do this only if you need an admin reference. If you need that, it is not redundant. Whilst it's more characters to type, it avoids the confusion that led OP to ask this question. This is a fine answer. I'm sure OP can figure out that 'new Administrator()' is shorthand for: Find a way to get an Administrator instance going.